# Accuracy of Forecast not Actuals

Tags: forecasting, accuracy, model-evaluation

I am trying to determine the accuracy of a set of forecast values. Not the accuracy of the Forecast to the Actuals (if that makes sense).

Here is my data sample:

```
Set    Forecast        Actual        O/(U)
1       3.1             2.1           1.1 
2       2.5             4.6          (2.1)
3       1.9             5.3          (3.3)
```

(there is some rounding here)

Now I know to calculate the error to actual error is `=ABS(O/U)/Actual`(My preference.)

My people want to do something different, can I compare the accuracy to the forecast with just this information? ie: `=1-(ABS(O/U)/Forecast)`.

If so in the case of set #3 the accuracy is `3.3/1.9 = 173%`.  It seems that the accuracy should be between 0 and 100 %.  Am I wrong? Or is there a better formula/method of getting what they want?

---

To try and clarify;
My group wants to determine the accuracy of a forecast by using the Forecast it as the base in their calculations, instead of the Actuals.

1) For determining forecast accuracy is the formula, `=1-(absolute value of the O/(U) divided by the Forecast value)`, an acceptable way of determining how accurate the forecast is.

2) If we are looking at the accuracy, shouldn't the result always be between 0 and 100 %.
Example #3 is `1-(|-3.3|/1.9) ---> 1-(3.3/1.9) ---> 1-(1.73) ---> -0.73 ---> -73%`

3) If the formula in question 1 **is not** the best method to calculate the accuracy, what is? Using only the sample data elements provided.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking about. Can you make this clearer?

Comment: gung, does this clarify things?

Comment: I really have no idea what this is about. It might help if you said something about your situation, your data, how the forecasts were computed, what would constitute 'accuracy' in this context, etc.

Comment: Some of my co-workers are creating a metric, I don't really agree with and I am trying to understand their logic. They want to report how often a forecast is incorrect and by how much.  To this end, they are suggesting I use the formula; 
=1-(ABS(O/U)/Forecast). 


We agree that the following formula, measures the Actual accuracy;
 =1-(ABS(O/U)/Actual) 

 However, they are interested in the accuracy of the Forecast (not the Actual) so they argue the first formula is more appropriate.  This argument does not make any sense to me because how can you have a negative accuracy?

Comment: Our managers want 100% to mean the forecast is always accurate and 0% to mean never accurate so they can determine which forecast models need improvement.  This data set is from a terrible model I have but it gave me these three examples for our discussion.  In simple terms these numbers are about how many outstanding bills will be paid vs not paid in a given period. IE I expect to receive 3.1K more outstanding bills to be paid than unpaid, instead I received 2.1K.